# Google CSE API returning multiple variations of same image

Tags: node.js, image, google-api, google-custom-search

When sending a request to the google CSE API, I end up getting multiple variations of the same image.

```js
const pagesToDownload = 1;
let pagesDownloaded = 0;

(async () => {
  const { google } = require('googleapis');
  
  const search = google.customsearch('v1');

  const query = 'pasta';

  let erroring = false;

  const nextPage = () => {
    if (pagesDownloaded != pagesToDownload && !erroring) {
      search.cse.list({
        q: query,
        auth: process.env['CX_KEY'],
        cx: "410a480db45d74a71",
        searchType: 'image',
        start: 1 + (pagesDownloaded * 10),
        fileType: "jpeg,jpg,png,gif,ico,bmp"
      }, async (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("REQUEST FAILED: " + err);
          erroring = true;
        } else {
          console.log(res);
          await downloadImagesFromSearchResult(res);
          pagesDownloaded++;
          nextPage();
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully downloaded %d images", pagesDownloaded * 10);
    }
  }
  nextPage();
})();
```

I've tried turning on and off the duplication filter, but neither make a difference. Here is an example of three pictures returned in the same request:

| Image 1 | Image 2 | Image 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Image 1] | [image: Image 2] | [image: Image 3] |

How could I go about removing duplicates?